# Negative values in time series forecast

Tags: python, statistics, time-series, arima

I am trying to perform univariate time series forecasting in python on a monthly rainfall dataset of 136 years using ARIMA.

My dataset is of the form:

YEAR          RAINFALL

2000-01-01    0

2000-02-01   128.2

2000-03-01    0

2000-04-01   289.3

.
.
.

I have two issues.

1) My forecast results have negative values though there are none in the training set and logically the rainfall values shouldn't be negative. My original data plot is as below.

[image]

Below is the graph of the test data and predicted values. As you can see the red curve of forecasted values extends below 0.

[image]

2) Since I have monthly data, the rainfall in some rows goes from a 0 to directly a high value in the next month, in which case the current value doesn't depend on the previous observed values as is the principle of autoregression. Is this what is causing a problem and not giving me a good fit? I have tried using yearly data instead but that doesn't give a right fit either and working with quarterly frequency will interrupt the actual monsoon period of the region of my dataset.

Comment: What does this have to do with Python? It looks like a question about statistics to me

Comment: I am implementing it using Python so any snippets of python code to help with the issue would be useful. But, you are right. Ive added statistics to my tags.

Answer (score 1):

The model is giving you its best guess.

It is simply extrapolating into a negative predicted value based on the observed inputs. This is where, "outside logic" comes in. Simply pass the predictions through a function that replaces negative values with 0. This is a common practice.

As simple as:

```
df[df < 0] = 0
```